# XML Parser and Google Maps Geocoding - Array Won't Populate

Tags: xml, arrays, performance, google-maps

I'm attempting to implement markers on my Google map on my page through city and country names within an XML file. Unfortunately, it appears that I'm unable to get the global array (countryList) that holds the country objects to stay populated outside of the XML parser. Using an alert within the parser, I can see that it holds 35 items, but outside it has 0. I'm looking for some insight, but I'm thinking that it has to do with the order in which these functions are being loaded. Due to the fact that the array is not holding any items, there are no cities to populate the map markers with.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "countries.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: parseXML
    });  
});
var countryList = [];
    function parseXML(xml) {
        $(xml).find("country").each(function() {
            var name = $(this).find("name").text();
            var capital = $(this).find("capital").text();


            countryList.push(new CountryObject(name, capital));

        });
        //alert(countryList.length);        this shows a count of 35`enter code here`
}

//alert(countryList.length);    this shows a count of 0

function CountryObject(name, capital) {
    this.name = name;
    this.capital = capital; 
}


var geocoder;
var map;
var markersArray = [];
var bounds;
var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
});

//plot initial point using geocode instead of coordinates (works just fine)
function initialize() {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4, 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'Toronto Canada'}, function(results, status) { 
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);

            markersArray.push(marker);
        }
        else{
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
    plotMarkers();
}

var locationsArray = [];

for (var j = 0; j < countryList.Length; j++) {
    var loc = countryList[j].capital + ' ' + countryList[j].name;
        locationsArray[j] = [countryList[j].capital, loc];
}


function plotMarkers(){
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < locationsArray.length; i++){
        codeAddresses(locationsArray[i]);
    }
}

function codeAddresses(address){
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address[1]}, function(results, status) { 
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(address[0]);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });

            bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);

            markersArray.push(marker); 
        }
        else{
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
```

Edit: I'm looking to populate the markers using the locationsArray by using the information gathered in the countryList array (instead of hard-coding the values which the majority of examples online use). However, I don't quite understand what I am missing to keep the countryList populated and I'm not too familiar with synchronous vs asynchronous besides what I've found on SO.

Comment: Can you define your question better? Edit the post and add a question to the end that will help others give you a good answer.

Comment: How long is your countries.xml?  Geocoding all those addresses on the fly risks running into the Geocoder quota and/or rate limit.  You can probably geocode about 10 locations reliably on page load without hitting the query limit, but that will depend on the load on Google's servers.  You should include the coordinates in your XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax call is asynchronous, you need to use the data inside the callback routine, where it is available.